# Regex in javascript- not working

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, date, comparison

I have following regex which I found from this website:

Bt somewhere the syntax is incorrect and it throws error:

```
var myDate = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)[0-9]{2};
```

Just to be clear:

Date can be anything between 01/01/1900 and 31/12/2099 but format should be strictly:

DD/MM/YYYY

I know there are several solutions on web, all similat but somehow it is throwing javascript error.

Probably syntax mistake because just above that i have put email validation which works fine:

```
var email = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
```

Comment: The first one misses a `/` at the end of the regex.

Comment: Also, you do not want to override the `Date` object.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Thanks, I have updated that, issue is with the pattern.

Comment: @Matt : Please can you post what updated one should be. That would be easier to understand.

Comment: @user1820973: I think that there is not a better explanation!?!

Comment: Are you aware that this regex will match many invalid dates?

Comment: Who is voting those kind of questions up? Seriously, I don´t get it.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. You are right. Got it now. Bugged with coding may be.

Comment: @Amberlamps - maybe those people who have made a slight syntax error in the past and not been able to see it (ie, every dev who has ever lived!). Not all questions have to be majorly cerebral.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for highlighting it. I just need basic one right now.

Comment: @Jamiec: Run the erronous code in your console. The error message is exactly the answer, that I would vote for in this thread: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`

Comment: @Amberlamps - erm... I did, and the answer you're refering ot is mine ;)

Comment: @Jamiec: :) I mean just the error message itself is the best answer! *Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.* - Antoine de Saint-Exupery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message from the console says

`SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal`

you're missing a `/` at the end of the line, so it should be

```
var myDate = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)[0-9]{2}/;
```

As pointed out in the comments, you *may* also have intended to put a `$` at the end before the `/`. This indicates to regex that you should match the end of the string (see your email example later in the OP).

As an aside; validating the *general format* of a date using regex is valid and worthwhile. Trying to validate it's an actual real, valid (ie, not 30 feb 2012) date using regex is barmy. The regex to be able to do it properly would be pages upon pages long!

Comment: And may be it needs `$` before last `/`

Comment: @pstr - maybe, but seeing as the OP didnt include it, im not going to assume it should be there.

Comment: +1 for your aside. `/^\d?\d\/\d?\d\/\d{4}$/` is enough to check the general format, or throw in some grouping parentheses to extract the pieces for a "real" date validation.